# How to understand the error from Eigen

Tags: c++, vector, eigen, eigen3

I have a problem with Eigen as below:

> LKSSP0.5psk: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:134: Eigen::Block::Block(XprType&, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix; int BlockRows = 2; int BlockCols = 2; bool InnerPanel = false; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `startRow >= 0 && BlockRows >= 1 && startRow + BlockRows <= xpr.rows() && startCol >= 0 && BlockCols >= 1 && startCol + BlockCols <= xpr.cols()' failed.
>   Command terminated by signal 6
>   27650.16user 5.67system 1:17:34elapsed 594%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 525396maxresident)k
>   328inputs+77192outputs (1major+17571minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Can anyone help understanding what it means so I can solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It means that you're doing something wrong and should step through your code with a debugger. If you don't know how to use a debugger I suggest you start with [this simple tutorial](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 4):

The key word in this message is "assertion". The [assertion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) has failed because basic matrix conditions are not met. Debug the code, find the line containing the assert and check the conditions.

This part:

> Assertion `startRow >= 0 && BlockRows >= 1 && startRow + BlockRows <=
>   xpr.rows() && startCol >= 0 && BlockCols >= 1 && startCol + BlockCols
>   <= xpr.cols()' failed.

lists the conditions that have to be met in order for the program to go on (e.g. startRow >= 0), but you don't know which are actually not met unless you debug the code and check. In this case, you have specified a negative number of columns/rows, referred to the element outside the matrix boundaries or the value of the BlockRows variable is less than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem. If you think this answer satisfies you, you may accept it apart from upvoting to indicate that you consider your problem to be solved.