Interpolate eigen splines with derivatives
I'm trying to interpolate a cubic spline with start&end derivative prescribed.
For that I created a wrapper for Eigen splines:
/**
* Cubic Spline.
* @tparam vec_t point type. Example: Eigen::Vector2d or Eigen::Vector3d
*/
template <typename vec_t, int dim, int spline_degree = 3>
class CubicSpline {
    private:
    typedef typename Eigen::Spline<double, dim, spline_degree>::KnotVectorType KnotVectorType;

    Eigen::MatrixXd m_Points;                               // Points.
    Eigen::Spline<double, dim, spline_degree> m_Spline;     // The spline object.
    Eigen::Spline<double, dim, spline_degree> m_SplineDer;  // The spline obtained with derivatives.
    KnotVectorType m_ChordLengths;  // Knot parameters, [0, 1].

    public:
    // Constructor.
    CubicSpline(const std::vector<vec_t>& points) {
        // Map data to matrix.
        m_Points = Eigen::MatrixXd::Map(points[0].data(), dim, points.size());
        // Intepolate spline.
        Eigen::ChordLengths(m_Points, m_ChordLengths);
        m_Spline = Eigen::SplineFitting<decltype(m_Spline)>::Interpolate(m_Points, spline_degree, m_ChordLengths);
    };

    // THIS FUNCTION FAILS!
    void withDerivatives()
            {
                Eigen::MatrixXd derivatives(2, 1);
                derivatives.setZero(); // Derivatives zero for this example.

                Eigen::Vector<int, 2> indices;
                indices << 0, m_Points.cols() - 1;
                
                m_SplineDer =
                    Eigen::SplineFitting<decltype(m_SplineDer)>::InterpolateWithDerivatives(
                        m_Points, derivatives, indices, spline_degree, m_ChordLengths);
            };

    // Value.
    constexpr vec_t valueAt(const double& t) { return m_Spline(t); };

};

// Common instantiations.
template class CubicSpline<Eigen::Vector2d, 2>;
template class CubicSpline<Eigen::Vector3d, 3>;

I then have a test in main cpp:
#include <unsupported/Eigen/Splines>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    // interpolation points.
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d> points(5);
    points[0] = Eigen::Vector2d{0.0, 0.0};
    points[1] = Eigen::Vector2d{10.0, 10.0};
    points[2] = Eigen::Vector2d{20.0, 20.0};
    points[3] = Eigen::Vector2d{30.0, 30.0};
    points[4] = Eigen::Vector2d{40.0, 40.0};

    auto spline = CubicSpline<Eigen::Vector2d, 2>(points);
    size_t N = 20;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        auto t = static_cast<double>(i) / N;

        // Evaluate some points.
        Eigen::Vector2d obtained = spline.valueAt(t);
        Eigen::Vector2d expected = t * (points[0] + points[4]);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            if (abs(obtained[j] - expected[j]) > 1e-3){
                printf("NOT GOOD: %i,%i \n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("now fit with derivatives:\n");
    spline.withDerivatives(); // <----THIS FAILS
    printf("DONE!");

    return 0;
}

Problem
It compiles but I get a weird Eigen error regarding cols&rows sizes.
output.s: /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/eigen/v3.4.0/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:146: Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>::Block(XprType&, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with XprType = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; int BlockRows = 1; int BlockCols = -1; bool InnerPanel = false; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `startRow >= 0 && blockRows >= 0 && startRow <= xpr.rows() - blockRows && startCol >= 0 && blockCols >= 0 && startCol <= xpr.cols() - blockCols' failed.
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV

Would somebody know how to solve this?
A working example
Can be found here

What's the compiler error? It would be helpful to supply a minimally reproducible example. You can start from here: https://godbolt.org/z/xjqYzKefT

@joergbrech I did not know I can add Eigen to godbolt. Amazing. I added a working example and can be found here

Just one more follow-up question, since I can't spot the problem at first sight: Are you open to using other libraries than Eigen for Geometry modeling? It seems like OpenCascade might me a better fit for your use case. Since you seem to be writing a wing designer: I am developer of tigl, a C++ library based on OpenCascade specifically for airplane design.

@joergbrech so the only reason I am with eigen is because it has a nice vector&matrix support which I most certainly need. The splines are not yet supported anyway so while I am working on this problem, I am also checking other libraries. You would recommend OpenCascade?

I would say it's not super simple, but it is ubiquitous as an Open Source Nurbs modeling library and it has been around for a while. So the functionality you need is supported and field tested by many other users

looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556024/how-to-understand-the-error-from-eigen describe identical errors, but I did not mark it as duplicate because I have no idea if the root-cause is identical

That assertion failure comes from the fact that when the
function that constructs the spline sets the equations
for each of the interpolation/derivative conditions
(which means writing the rows a matrices A and b that
will make the system A * x = b, where x are the spline
parameters) it tries to write, either in A or in b, outside
the sizes those matrices have.
It means the sizes of those matrices (computed from the sizes  of the input data, i.e., actual parameters in the call to InterpolateWithDerivatives) are less than they should be, for the problem to be solved. To put it simply, there's not enough information given to InterpolationWithDeriatives.
The particular cause of the problem in the code you posted (found after not a short session of debugging), is just the first line of:
Eigen::MatrixXd derivatives(2, 1);
derivatives.setZero(); // Derivatives zero for this example.

Since these are parametric splines, you have to provide derivatives for both x and y, for each of the two points you have chosen, so the correct size is:
Eigen::MatrixXd derivatives(2, 2);
derivatives.setZero(); // Derivatives zero for this example.

As a bonus :), I plotted (by using printf to format data as json and copy-pasting from the console) the spline values in the interval [0, 1],
for both simple interpolation and the case with derivatives,and one case see the zero derivatives for x(t) and y(t) in the top chart, by the fact that the points are not uniformly distributed, but are "agglomerating" towards the two ends where the derivatives were set to zero. Or even more clear, the plot of the coordinates as function of the spline parameter t ∈ [0, 1], x(t), y(t) and their derivatives x'(t) and y'(t).
